# Error in `[.default(P, a, ) : incorrect number of dimensions`

Tags: r

R keeps giving the error:
`Error in [.default(P, a, ) : incorrect number of dimensions`

What i am trying to do is use values that I have created for a team's home and away attacking and defending strength and then use these values to create a probability table to find the expected goals between 2 teams.

My code:

```
ProbTable <- function(Attack_Def_strength,Home.Team,Away.Team) 

{

 teams <- rownames(Attack_Def_strength$Club)

 P <- Attack_Def_strength$Club

 a <- which(teams == Home.Team)

 b <- which(teams == Away.Team)

 x <- exp(P[a,]$'Home Attacking Strength' - P[b,]$'Home Defending Strength')

 y <- exp(P[b,]$'Away Atacking Strength' - P[a,]$'Away Defending Strength')

 A <- as.numeric()

 B <- as.numeric()

for(i in 0:7) {

A[(i+1)] <- dpois(i,x)
    B[(i+1)] <- dpois(i,y)
  }

A[8] <- 1 - sum(A[1:8])

 B[8] <- 1 - sum(B[1:8])

 name <- c("0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7+")

 zero <- mat.or.vec(8,1)

 C <- data.frame(row.names=name)

 for(j in 1:8) {

   for(k in 1:8) {

     C[j,k] <- A[k]*B[j]
    }
  }
  colnames(C) <- name
  return(round(C*100,2))
}

Probabilities <- ProbTable(Attack_Def_strength,"Arsenal","QPR")
```

This is what the traceback shows:

```
Error in `[.default`(P, a, ) : incorrect number of dimensions 
4.
NextMethod("[") 
3.
`[.factor`(P, a, ) 
2.
P[a, ] 
1.
ProbTable(Attack_Def_strength, "Arsenal", "QPR")
```

Comment: can you provide a sample dataset, in order to understand the function and reproduce the error ?

Comment: Unless `teams` is a global variable (and it really shouldn't), the `teams` from `which(teams == Home.Team)` inside `PropTable` is not defined; ditto for vector `P` as well as `A` and `B`. The function is a bit of a mess, and it's difficult to help without any reproducible sample data/code.